# Is there a way to force Windows 10 to arrange windows as it was done with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to force Windows 10 to tile, cascade, stack windows as it was done with Windows 7? The "new" "better" way could be fine if you are working with two windows, but this new notion of having to drag windows to the corners and sides to then select the other window, is not productive for me. Doing so with a multi-monitor setup is a nightmare, but it becomes a night terror if your are using two computers with the Microsoft program "Mouse Without Borders".

With Windows 7 you just right click on the task bar selected "side by side" and all windows got properly rearranged, easy, just one or two clicks. Those options are available on Windows 10 task bar but it doesn't work, windows are not properly re-sized, the entire screen is not occupied, you select side by side and you get tiles, etc.

Best regards.

Comment: I am able to arrange Windows “side by side” on Windows 10.  How they are arranged is identical on Windows 7.  I am confused what behavior you want to change

Comment: Ramhound, yes sometime it works sometimes it doesn't. Try this open four windows and ask to arrange them side by side. In my case it tiles the windows and left an empty space in the desktop.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "Windows Snap" feature controllable via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys. <kbd>↑</kbd> for upper corner or maximizing the Window, <kbd>←</kbd> for left side or left Monitor if pressed repeatedly, same for <kbd>→</kbd> but on the right side. Press <kbd>↑</kbd> for the lower corners or minimizing the window.

[image: four-by-four]

[image: four images on Windows 7]

[image: Show Windows side-by-side]

[image: four windows side-by-side]

With this technique you can move and arrange windows faster than dragging and placing them with the mouse.

If you want to arrange windows by right clicking on Taskbar and selecting *Show Windows Side by Side*.

[image: Taskbar]

It will then arrange two Windows side by side as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Side-by-Side]

somehow I can't get Windows 10 to arrange four windows four by four by selecting *Show Windows Side by Side* as in Windows 7, but with snap you get the same result although slower.

Comment: Nordlys you are talking about snap assists that's Windows 10 new "better" option. Ok so how do you arrage 4 windows side by side with this method. In Windows 7 it was just right click on the task bar choose side by side and done.

Comment: @3d1l I updated my answer. Please ping me if you have further problems with this, or I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Nordlys I really appretiate your effort but again that's aero snap asist. On the four windows, that's not side by side that's tile and you had to use eight key combos for that. Take a look at this post from the Microsoft Forums (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/show-windows-side-by-side-does-not-work/ac08c8c7-8ae0-4f09-8eb6-fdac01d2a047?rtAction=1538838000727), read the entire thread.

Comment: @3d1l the four windows - windows 7 (fourth image) image *is* actually not windows aero, but side by side. But I understand what you meant, and do not have a solution for your issue. I'll let this answer stand, as it provides a workaround for users with the same issue.

Comment: Nordlys, so far your option, is not exactly what I'm looking for but for now it is what's available. One question, How do you "stack" using the key combos. If I use the stack option from the task bar the same problems happens, empty spaces, displaced windows, etc. To simplify things lets define only two windows and stack them one on top of the other using the full screen.

Comment: As far as I know you cant stack with the key combinations.

Comment: And please don't accept this answer, if it isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I didn't select your answer as the "final" answer but I did marked it as useful.